# AWX - enrich inventory with ansible facts

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

In AWX I created an inventory with a VMware vCenter source that fetch hosts from vCenter.
It's working well and I got all my VMware VMs in the AWX hosts.

Now I'd like ansible to gather facts on these hosts gathered by the VMWare inventory plugin to enrich the inventory and create groups based on these additional facts. I got a playbook that can do exactly that.

How can I do that so that I can sync the inventory, and then both the gathering of hosts from vmware and the enrichment of these hosts with ansible facts would happen ?

Comment: So, you want to combine the fact gathering of Ansible and VMware? What is the actual goal here which has to be achieved?

Comment: @KevinC yes. For example the os release given by the vmware plugin is not as reliable as the one given by ansible facts. I want to use the one given by ansible facts instead of the one used by the vmware inventory plugin for hosts grouping, as well as other facts given by ansible.

Comment: If you can paste both fact gathering on pastebin, then I can make it work.